# Inserir texto das textboxs e ler somente depois dos |

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá, queria saber como posso fazer para que as 2 textboxs insere os ID deste jeito no txt:

arquivo.txt:

```
id|192919 <---- textbox1
id2|29b9a92 <---- textbox2
```

E depois quando abrir o programa de novo coloca assim nas textboxs:

```
textbox1: 192919
textbox2: 29b9a92
```

Tentei substring, split, mas estou com dúvida pois os números podem variar ao colocar na textbox, e para pegar também não sei como faz pois varia. Como posso fazer? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está um pouco confusa a pergunta, mas para pegar o valor depois do **|**. é possível usar o `split` e passar o índice.

O `split` fará um `array` de `strings`, porém caso tenha mais de um **|** o `array` terá um índice maior.

```
string id1 = "id|192919";
string id2 = "id2|29b9a92";

string valor1 = id1.Split('|')[1];
string valor2 = id2.Split('|')[1];
```

Caso tenha a possibilidade de ter mais de um **|**. Pode-se usar o `Substring` junto ao `IndexOf` que irá pegar o índice do primeiro **|**

```
string id1 = "id|19291|9";
string id2 = "id2|29b9a9|2";

string valor1 = id1.Substring(id1.IndexOf("|") + 1);
string valor2 = id2.Substring(id2.IndexOf("|") + 1);
```

Comment: Como posso salvar em um txt essas strings: string id1 = "id|192919";
string id2 = "id2|29b9a92"; para depois pegar com essas strings:  string valor1 = id1.Substring(id1.IndexOf("|") + 1);
string valor2 = id2.Substring(id2.IndexOf("|") + 1);

Comment: De uma olhada [nesse tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file) da MS para salvar o arquivo

Comment: Ok consegui, mas como pego esses valores id1 e id2 dentro do txt e faço o split, é isso que eu quero, valeu.

Comment: Você tem algum botão no form? se sim, dentro do click dele faça `string id1 =  textbox1.Text;` de uma olhada [nesse video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giIOrc6ysSU)

Answer (score 0):

Se a sua string sempre seguir essa padronização o split resolve. Utilize este método:

```
public static string GetId(string str)
    {
        var str1 = str.Split('|');
        return str1[1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para escrever no arquivo:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("arquivo.txt", new string[] 
{
    string.Format("{0}|{1}", textbox1.ID, textbox1.Text),
    string.Format("{0}|{1}", textbox2.ID, textbox2.Text),
});
```

Para ler:

```
string[] linhas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("arquivo.txt");
foreach (string linha in linhas)
{
    string[] separadores = new string[1] { "|" };
    string[] tokens = linha.Split(separadores);
    if (token.Length == 2)
    {
        string id = token[0];
        string valor = token[1];

        Func<string, System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Windows.Forms.Control> getControle = (id, controle) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                if (controle.ID == id)
                {
                    return controle;
                }

                if (controle.Controls != null && controle.Controls.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var c in controle.Controls)
                    {
                        if (c.ID == id)
                        {
                            return c;
                        }

                        System.Windows.Forms.Control child;
                        child = getControle(c, id);
                        return child;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textbox = getControle(id, <seuform>) as System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;
        if (textbox != null)
        {
            textbox.Text = valor;
        }
    }
}
```